# Box Collider center relative to GameObject

Tags: unity

I'm trying to get the distance from the BoxCollider center of a gameobject to the bottom of that same BoxCollider. Note that the center of the collider is slighty modified.

[image]

So far, I have:

```
float halfHeightCollider = (bounds.size.y / 2);
```

I tried the following to take care of the slight modification:

```
float halfHeightCollider = bounds.center.y + (bounds.size.y / 2);
```

But seems like `bounds.center` give me the position of the center of the BoxCollider in the world, not relative to the gameobject, like in the inspector:

[image]

That value is the one I want. How can I get it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the center in y-axis from `gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().center.y`.

You will get the total size in y-axis of the  collider from `gameObject.GetComponent<BoxCollider>().size.y`.

Then take the y-size/2 and **subtract** center value in y-axis from it.

Comment: Okay, now I get what I was doing wrong. I store the BoxCollider bounds reference in a variable and that value wasn't getting updated. Thank you!